# How to remove pagination from slider in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pagination

Here is the script for slider:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#slides').slides({
            preload: true,
            preloadImage: 'img/loading.gif',
            play: 5000,
            pause: 2500,
            hoverPause: true,
            animationStart: function(current){
                $('.caption').animate({
                    bottom:-35
                },100);
                if (window.console && console.log) {
                    // example return of current slide number
                    console.log('animationStart on slide: ', current);
                };
            },
            animationComplete: function(current){
                $('.caption').animate({
                    bottom:0
                },200);
                if (window.console && console.log) {
                    // example return of current slide number
                    console.log('animationComplete on slide: ', current);
                };
            },
            slidesLoaded: function() {
                $('.caption').animate({
                    bottom:0
                },200);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

above script added in head section and also these

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/slides.min.jquery.js"></script>
```

included in head tag.

Here is the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/j88u02o2/

In the above i have added html and slides.min.jquery.js file.

When i run above all codes, pagination displayed. but i don't need .. so i tried to remove it.. but i can't. still it shows like numbers..

my page look like this: http://s28.postimg.org/rs8wlvmwt/Untitled_1.png

And i need, working of slideshow like this link http://securedcommunications.com/

Can anybody help me to achieve this one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please make Fiddle properly so that I can modify it quickly .You please check yourself on Your jsfiddle link  http://jsfiddle.net/j88u02o2/  .Its not working.

Comment: No issue I made it Myself , I am checking issue http://jsfiddle.net/j88u02o2/3/

Comment: You asked "How to remove pagination from slider in jquery?" , I answered it . For more functionality you can ask another question.

Comment: Hi , see in your URL of the site you want slider like ,it uses Slider plugin different from your plugin. It uses -> http://securedcommunications.com/Include/js/cross-slide.js Plugin .

Comment: mam ,Hi Got it. This is whom we call a Software engineer / web developer  :) -> Did you understand now `What are the duties of web dev.?` http://jsfiddle.net/j88u02o2/59/    ,Web dev is one of the smartest person. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried pagination setting and set to false

```
 pagination: {
  active: false
    // [string] Can be either "slide" or "fade".
 },
 .......................
```

but it didnt work , so better solution is use display none to its wrapper .

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/j88u02o2/14/)

```
.pagination{
    display:none;
}
```

**Update**

As per new Update and new JS slider , [Here is DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j88u02o2/59/)

What I did is ->

```
$(function() {
        $('#slides').crossSlide({
            speed: 40,
            fade: 1
        }, [
            { src: 'http://securedcommunications.com/Include/Images/home/photo-2.jpg', dir: 'up', alt: 'Our Business is to Encrypt and Secure Your Communications', href: '#'  },
            { src: 'http://securedcommunications.com/Include/Images/home/photo-2.jpg', dir: 'down', alt: 'The Solution for Secured Communications and Privacy.', href: '#'  }
            /*  */
        ], function(idx, img, idxOut, imgOut) {
            if (idxOut == undefined) {
                if(idx == 0 || idx == 3 || idx == 6 || idx == 9){
                    document.getElementById('crossSlideCaption').style.marginTop = '-430px';
                    document.getElementById('crossSlideCaption').style.marginLeft = '-485px';
                }else if(idx == 1 || idx == 4 || idx == 7 || idx == 10 || idx == 12){
                    document.getElementById('crossSlideCaption').style.marginTop = '-280px';
                    document.getElementById('crossSlideCaption').style.marginLeft = '-100px';
                }else{
                    document.getElementById('crossSlideCaption').style.marginTop = '-52px';
                    document.getElementById('crossSlideCaption').style.marginLeft = '-485px';
                };
                $('div.caption').text(img.alt).animate({ opacity: 1.0 })
            } else {
                $('div.caption').animate({ opacity: 0 })
            }});
        $('div.caption').show().css({ opacity: 0 })
    });
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="example">
        <div id="slides" style="width:970px;height:430px;"></div>
            <div id="" class="" style="position:relative; width:970px; margin:auto;" align="">
                <div id="crossSlideCaption" class="caption">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And add 2 JS files in

1. http://securedcommunications.com/Include/js/cross-slide.js
2. http://securedcommunications.com/Include/js/jquery-easing.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70470/discussion-between-jquery-php-magento-com-and-rani).

Comment: a little busy will see it later.

Comment: I m in company right now doing company work and I think Plugin supports image only .So you extend jQuery plugin by writing your own code for video ! :) Enjoy

Comment: @rani You need to ADD functionality for video , so extend plugin ! :)

Comment: @rani mademji you are using this plugin for Sliding image -> http://securedcommunications.com/Include/js/cross-slide.js OK ?So you need to write more code in this JS file so it will work with Video also .So if you know Core Javascript And jQuery , modify the plugin and use it for video.

Comment: @rani No , both sliders DON'T support video , Check these plugins -> http://kreaturamedia.com/layerslider-responsive-jquery-slider-plugin/ AND http://bxslider.com/examples/video  .And 1 more , please gather requirements first so that you can fix which slider to use till the end ,and you dont have to waste time for many sliders

Comment: I mean you need to first note down Requirements and then go for One perfect slider which fulfills your requirement.What happened with your approach is you jumped on multiple slider because `This slider doesnot support this and that` .So use only one slider and note down requirements first before Coding.

Comment: @rani yes..wats the issue?

Comment: @rani , Sorry I cant help you now , as Stackoverflow WILL remove your reputation and set to 1 and mine too and also your account will be blocked .It happened with me . If a person answers lots of question for same user and get upvotes , its considered fraud.So thanks , please do R&D or contact their support.

Comment: @rani , please contact me on my email.

Comment: @rani , i m in office , see you in the evening.

Comment: @rani , helo mam , ask your senior.

Comment: @rish , Who is this ? I know rani only.

Comment: Ok nice.What is the issue ?